# Schedule::Cron never returns to main script

Tags: perl, cron

I am trying to run a Perl script (test.pl) once every minute without using `crontab`.  Since I will not have access to write cron jobs into `/etc/cron.d/`, I am using the Perl module `Schedule::Cron`.

I have included the code for test.pl in a script that is running continuously and  given code like:

```
my $cron = new Schedule::Cron(sub {}); 
$cron->add_entry("* * * * *",\&test_function); 
$cron->run(nofork=>1)
```

The issue is that the line

```
$cron->run(nofork=>1)
```

never returns back to the main script, and it is not executing any code that are given after that.

I need a solution for this to run cron in the background (using `Schedule::Cron`) and then return back to the main script for executing the remaining script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
$cron->run(nofork=>1)
```

to:

```
$cron->run(detach=>1)
```

This returns immediately to the main script.  From [Schedule::Cron](https://metacpan.org/module/Schedule%3a%3aCron) (detach):

> If set to a true value the scheduler process is detached from the
>   current process (UNIX only).